# MTV newbie issues with Python Django

Tags: python, django

I am kinda new with the MVC and MTV concept and i am trying to learn Python Django. I want to make catalog with books, must have add and delete functionality. I am trying to follow best practices and working with Generic views, but kinda stuck at the end, i feel that i am missing something very small but i cant figure it out - to be honest i am very exhausted at this moment and i dont have much time. So this is my code:
Models:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pages = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class BooksForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
```

Views:

```
# coding: utf-8

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import ListView, UpdateView, CreateView, DetailView


from models import Book


class BooksDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "books_portal/details.html"


class BooksCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "books_portal/add.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('books_portal')


class BooksUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "books_portal/add.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('books_portal')


class BooksListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'books_list'
    template_name = "books_portal/index.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.order_by('author')[:5]
```

Templates:
add.html

```
{% extends "books_portal/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Add books{% endblock %}

{% block extracss %}
<style>
    .top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }
    .bs-docs-nav { background-color: #563d7c; }
</style>
{% endblock extracss %}

{% block content %}
        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row top-buffer">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    {{form.title.label_tag}}
                    <input type="text" value="" class=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    {{form.author.label_tag}}
                    <input type="text" value="" class=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>{% block title %}{{title|default:"Book Library"}}{% endblock %}</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            {% block extracss %}{% endblock extracss %}
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="{% url 'books_portal' %}" class="navbar-brand">Books Portal</a>
                </div>
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>

            {% block extrajs %}{% endblock extrajs %}
        </body>
    </html>
```

details.html

```
{% extends "books_portal/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Details{% endblock %}

{% block extracss %}
<style>
    .top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }
    .bs-docs-nav { background-color: #4CD085; }
</style>
{% endblock extracss %}

{% block content %}
         <div class="row top-buffer">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <strong>Title:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    {{book.title}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <strong>Author:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    {{book.author}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer">
                </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 text-center"><a href="{% url 'books_portal' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">OK</a></div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends "books_portal/base.html" %}

    {% block title %}Collection of books{% endblock %}

    {% block extracss %}
    <style>
        .top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }
        .bs-docs-nav { background-color: #563d7c; }
    </style>
    {% endblock extracss %}

    {% block content %}
        <table class="table table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Title</th>
                <th class="text-center">Author</th>
                <th class="text-center">Edit</th>
            </tr>
            {% for book in books_list %}
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="{% url 'books_details' pk=book.id%}">{{ book.title }}</a></td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ book.author }}</td>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="{% url 'books_edit' pk=book.id%}" class="btn btn-default">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center"><a href="{% url 'books_add' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add</a></div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Currently i cant add or delete any books, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If i miss something i will gladly add it, just don't know what .

Comment: You've posted far too much code but never described what the actual problem is. What is actually going wrong? What errors do you get?

Comment: Ok i deserved the - you are right, like i said i am too tired. The problem is that i can't figure it out what logic and where exactly must be implemented in order to be able to add and delete books. I mean should i put it in the Model or somewhere else ?

Comment: Why do you need logic? You already have a CreateView, that's all you need to add books. There's a [DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview) you can use too.

Comment: Okey the problem is that CreateView doesn't work. It doesn't add any books in the ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cut and pasted all your code, plus a relevant urls.py, into a new project. The immediate problem is that you're not showing any form errors in your add.html. You can just add `{{ form.errors }}` at the top of the template.

Once you've done that, you'll see the actual issue: you're not providing all relevant fields when creating your book. In fact, Django can't see *any* fields, because you haven't given any of the inputs `name` attributes. Really, you shouldn't create the `input` elements manually: you should get Django to do that, because then it also takes responsibility for prepopulating the field with the existing value either when re-showing the form with errors, or when editing an existing Book. It should look like this:

```
{{ form.title.label_tag }}
{{ form.title }}
{{ form.title.errors }}
```

Then the outstanding issue is that you're not including the `isbn` or `pages` fields, which your model is treating as required. You can either set them as `blank=False` in the model, or use an `exclude` list in the ModelForm. Either way, you'll need `null=False` in the model field for `pages`.

Or, of course, you can add them to the form. To be honest, the easiest thing for you to do now, while you're learning, is to replace all the HTML inside your `<form>` tag with just `{{ form.as_p }}`, so that Django outputs everything for you.

Comment: Thank you, very much man. I appreciate your dedication to my problem. With your help i was able to "fix" my noobish code.